# How can I sort an 'object_id' array so that I can get the relational values from the database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have some information in my database like 'author', 'book' etc., that are all related to a 'note_id', which is related to a 'user'. I query the DB for the note id and I get this back:

***note_id assoc array***

```
Array ( [0] => 32 ) Array ( [0] => 31 ) Array ( [0] => 33 ) Array ( [0] => 34 ) Array ( [0] => 35 ) Array ( [0] => 36 ) Array ( [0] => 37 ) Array ( [0] => 38 ) Array ( [0] => 39 ) Array ( [0] => 40 ) Array ( [0] => 41 ) Array ( [0] => 42 ) Array ( [0] => 43 ) Array ( [0] => 44 ) Array ( [0] => 45 ) Array ( [0] => 46 )
```

What I am trying to do is to use all of these values to grab each book review (with author, book, etc.) and then display it to the user in order, one by one.

What's the next step for me to be able to do this?

Here is the code I am using:

```
<?php
    //Starting session
    session_start();

    //Includes mass includes containing all the files needed to execute the full script
    //Also shows homepage elements without customs

    include ('includes/mass.php');

    //Set the  session variable
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];

    //Check to see if logged in
    if (isset($username)) {
        //Check all databases assoc with the notes for username submissions

        $sql_for_username_submission = "SELECT note_id FROM notes WHERE user = '$username'";
        $get_data = mysql_query($sql_for_username_submission);
        while ($data_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_data)) {
             $name_id = $data_row;
        }
    }   
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered looking into using [joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) so that you could have MySQL automatically lookup the data for you without separate queries?

Comment: Yes. That is what i did previously but i found that it was a bit too complicated because i will be fetching data from 4 different tables.

Comment: If they all share a common ID linking matching records, it's probably actually far more efficient to join the 4 tables than it would be to run 4 queries. But if you absolutely do not want to use joins, then you'd basically run queries within the loop that look like `"SELECT field1,field2,... FROM othertable1 WHERE note_id = $current_note_id;"` and then get the result from that, for each query.